# Login and Registration page breaks after changing theme

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, login, customer-account, register

I am currently working on ver 1.9.2.4 and after installing a new theme, the login and registration page just breaks. I haven't made any changes to the base files of magento. Here's the link http://www.getintenso.com/demo/default/customer/account/login/ that how it should look and I am also attaching the screenshot of my store. Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?
[image]
 Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any breaks on that page.

Comment: Brother the whole page is messed up if you look at the screenshot. I have also provided the link above that how it should look

Comment: Please take a look to this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzzryzi04c66d13/Screenshot%202016-04-25%2015.18.04.png?dl=0. You should try to clean your cache. Both of browser cache and Magento cache?

Comment: Yeah that's how it should look but it's not looking like that. Have a look at my website now http://staging.vivavoyager.com/customer/account/login/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct Configuration under `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Package` and `System -> Configuration -> Design -> Themes` because the template content seems to be different then what shown on the demo URL.

Comment: Everything is configured correctly there. Any other tips?

Comment: All I could say is there is some problem with your theme's customer templates, as the HTML of Registration form is completely different then the demo